# SQL Server query with paging - different time for different pages

Tags: sql-server, performance

I have table with 12000 records and I have a query where this table is joined with few tables + paging. I measure time using `SET STATISTICS TIME ON/OFF`. For first pages it's very fast but the closer to the last page the more time it takes. Is it normal?

Comment: It depends on how you do the paging. Using `row_number()` or `offset fetch` then yes that is what to be expected.

Comment: @Mikael Eriksson Yes, I use ROW_NUMBER(). Is it to possible to do paging using another way (not row_number or offset-fetch) without time increasing?

Comment: Depends on the situation. I have seen one (never done) using an api cursor. And you could of course remember the last value you received that you use in the order by and fetch the next X number of rows using that value in a where clause. `select TOP(X) ... from ... where Col1 > @OldMaxCol1 order by Col1`. In that case it can do a seek on Col1 and scan the supporting index for X rows only.

Answer (score 2):

This is normal because SQL Server has no way to directly seek to a given page of a logical query. It scans through a stream of results until it has arrived at the page you wanted.

If you want constant time paging you need to provide some kind of seek key on an index. For example if you can guarantee that your `ID int` column has consecutive values starting with `1` you can get any page in constant time simply by saying `WHERE ID >= ... and ID < ...`.

I'm sure you'll find other approaches on the web but there's nothing built into the product.